# symfony repository memory leak

Tags: symfony, memory

This code in trollService.php (Symfony 2.3):

```
public function trolling()
{
    $repository = $this->entityManager->getRepository('TrollBundle:Troll');
    $trolls = $repository->findAll(); //memory leak
    return memory_get_usage();
}
...
//somewhere:
while(1)
{
    $result = $trollService->trolling();
}
```

The $result from N iteration is always > N-1 iteration. How is this possible? Is not $trolls variable a local variable, which should be automatically delete after return from function? O.o

So, how can I clear memory before next iteration?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Doctrine keeps in memory already fetched objects: is a method for avoid too much db interrogation.

This mechanism is known as ***identity map***

> This is called “Identity Map” pattern, which means Doctrine keeps a
>   map of each entity and ids that have been retrieved per PHP request
>   and keeps returning you the same instances.
>
> Remember also that by default logging of the SQL connection is set to
>   the value of `kernel.debug`, so if you have idebug set to true the
>   every SQL command get stored in memory for each iteration.

(from [doctrine2 documentation](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/working-with-objects.html#entities-and-the-identity-map))

If you want to clear memory you have to use `$this->entityManager->clear();` as your last instruction of `trolling()` function

```
public function trolling()
{
    $repository = $this->entityManager->getRepository('TrollBundle:Troll');
    $trolls = $repository->findAll(); //memory leak
    $this->entityManager->clear(); //here
    return memory_get_usage();
}
```